# rails passenger deployment - Could not find table 'users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I made the [passengers's offical tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/) with no error. I pull my code from git and used this commands

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test
bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate
```

my database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

log/production.log:

```
I, [2015-08-28T15:54:47.310372 #32086]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 176.219.167.108 at 2015-08-28 15:54:47 -0400
I, [2015-08-28T15:54:47.334003 #32086]  INFO -- : Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
I, [2015-08-28T15:54:47.365923 #32086]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
F, [2015-08-28T15:54:47.367834 #32086] FATAL -- :
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/models/ability.rb:5:in `initialize'
```

I checked I've users table with this command on rails console

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

btw, I use devise gem for users.
I'm absolute beginner about rails, I hope the info which I write is enough to you understand problem.

and my server info: Digital Ocean 5$ droplet. Ubuntu 14.04. Nginx, passenger, rvm, ruby 2.2.2.

and my 500 page : [image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2qkoz07.jpg)

Comment: first check is `sqlite` database is present on server or not. Then first create the database using `rake db:create`, after that `rake db:migrate`

Comment: As you can see in my post I executed bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate. And I have sqlite db.

Comment: First you have to create the database, then you should migrate.

Comment: I tried first db:create and then db:migrate, but doesn't work. still get 500 error.

Comment: mb you have a problem with the ability class...? ability.rb:5

Comment: this line using User model(users table) it's the problem already.

Comment: http://oi59.tinypic.com/350kkds.jpg

Comment: try 'bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"' It looks like you run migrations for development env.

Comment: @railsr thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by simply running the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

However, I don't advise you use SQLite in production, as this type of database is best for testing and development purposes. You might want to look into using PostgreSQL. The following should work for you:

in your **Gemfile**, add:

```
gem 'pg', :group => :production
```

Run `bundle install`.
Then in **database.yml** use:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000

login: &login
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASS'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  <<: *login
  database: your_database_name
```

For security reasons, it's best not to write your database username and password in plaintext within files in your Rails app. Far better to set them as environment variables. To do this, edit the **~/.bash_profile** file on your Droplet and add the following:

```
export DATABASE_USER=your_username
export DATABASE_PASS=your_password
```

Exit that file and run `source ~/.bash_profile` from the command line to load these new settings into memory.

You will then need to create the PostgreSQL database, for which there are [plenty of guides online](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Once that's done you will want to run the same command that works for SQLite when running migrations in production:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I solved the problem. That's just a personal blog, that's why I use sqlite. Sure, I will use postgres for real products ^^
And thanks for great advices.